# foreach loop ignoring array order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a disparate bunch of objects that I'm trying to group together. They are job interviews. I want them grouped by Job Title and then by time. From latest to earliest. So far so good. There's probably a far less convoluted way to do what I'm attempting, but the following code was working for me until I was asked to put the nearest interview date first.

```
function interview_sort($interviews) {

    $titles = get_job_titles();

    foreach($interviews as $interview) {

        if(strtotime($interview->getStart()) > strtotime('-2 weeks')) {

            // get all the interview times no more than two weeks old
            $times[] = strtotime($interview->getStart());

        }
    }

    // we only want one of each
    $times = array_unique($times);

    // sort them from latest to earliest
    rsort($times);

    // we want the closest date first
    $closest = find_closest_date($times, strtotime('today'));

    //store it
    $date = $times[$closest];

    // bin it from it's original position
    unset($times[$closest]);

    // put it on the front
    array_unshift($times, $date);

    print_r($times);

    // group by job title
    foreach ($titles as $title) {

        // group by interview time
        foreach($times as $time) {

            foreach ($interviews as $interview) {

                if($interview->getPostingTitle() == $title && strtotime($interview->getStart()) == $time) {

                    $grouped[$title][$time][] = $interview;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $grouped;
}
```

The point at which the `print_r($times)` is written outputs the array with the first time as the nearest, then the following times from latest to earliest as desired. However, the `$grouped` array is in the original order of latest to earliest.

Comment: I think you're still adding items to the array in title order. So if nearest interview is in title 3, the loop will actually display the latest to oldest interview in title 1, followed by title 2, then only in title 3 you will find closest interview first then others.

Comment: If the data needs to be grouped by title with nearest interview first then the entire title containing interview with nearest date needs to come frist.

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared the array before your foreach loop.

```
function interview_sort($interviews) {

    $times = [];
    $titles = get_job_titles();

    foreach($interviews as $interview) {

        if(strtotime($interview->getStart()) > strtotime('-2 weeks')) {

            // get all the interview times no more than two weeks old
            $times[] = strtotime($interview->getStart());

        }
    }
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks, but hasn't made any difference, unfortunately.

Comment: Is your print_r($times); showing the correct order of times? I ask, because you have another foreach loop which loops through $titles and your return value of your function is returning $grouped which is created from the titles loop?

Comment: yes, the `print_r($times)` is printing in the required order. It's as if it's looping through the array before it was altered.